# How can these buttons be modified with CSS in order to have a different color/text color/etc?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to customize some buttons on a site in which templates are utilized and cannot be modified, so I have to simply utilize a CSS file in order to stylize the elements and I cannot directly modify the way the buttons are create. However, they are a bit complex with a table for each button, and they are all within their own table cell. How can I set the buttons to have a different background color? I was only able to change the buttons to allow for the border to be thicker on hover, but there is an issue with a grey background still showing up no matter how I attempt to modify the background.

My code:

```css
.bntBgB {
    background-color: #122d98;
}
.bntBgB:hover {
    background-color: #122d98;
    border-width: 0.2rem;
}
.bntBgT {
    background: none;
    border: solid 1px #384e86;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: "Roboto-Light";
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 0.04688rem;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 300px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0.6em 0 0.75em;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background 0.25s ease;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
.bntBgT:hover {
    background: #031136;
    border: solid 1px #8fa0ca;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<table id='tbl_secondarycustbtn_set_prim' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' class='uir-button' style='margin-right:6px;cursor:hand;' role='presentation'>
    <tr id='tr_secondarycustbtn_set_prim' class='pgBntG'>
        <td id='tdleftcap_secondarycustbtn_set_prim'><img src='/images/nav/ns_x.gif' class='bntLT' border='0' height='50%' width='3' alt='' />
            <img src='/images/nav/ns_x.gif' class='bntLB' border='0' height='50%' width='3' alt='' /> </td>
        <td id='tdbody_secondarycustbtn_set_prim' height='20' valign='top' nowrap class='bntBgB'>
            <input type='button' style='' class='rndbuttoninpt bntBgT' value='Set As Primary' id='secondarycustbtn_set_prim' name='secondarycustbtn_set_prim' onclick="nlFireEvent(getButton('custbtn_set_prim'), 'click'); return false;" onmousedown="this.setAttribute('_mousedown','T'); setButtonDown(true, false, 
this);" onmouseup="this.setAttribute('_mousedown','F'); setButtonDown(false, 
false, this);" onmouseout="if(this.getAttribute('_mousedown')=='T') 
setButtonDown(false, false, this);" onmouseover="if(this.getAttribute('_mousedown')=='T') setButtonDown(true, false,
this);"></td>
        <td id='tdrightcap_secondarycustbtn_set_prim'>
            <img src='/images/nav/ns_x.gif' height='50%' class='bntRT' border='0' width='3' alt=''>
            <img src='/images/nav/ns_x.gif' height='50%' class='bntRB' border='0' width='3' alt=''>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Button Image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7Lxy.jpg

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: It seems that the images that are built in to the template are in fact the button background, so is there a way to set a background to appear by perhaps hiding the image or modifying another attribute?

Comment: Try `background: none !important`. I don't see where your styles is being rewritten, from your snippet everything kind of works. I bet you're speaking on a button which is affected by another styles as well and they have bigger priority than yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good chance that their might be an existing inline style or some other style with a higher specificity. Open your dev tools and search for the background color to see from where exactly the style is generated.

Also try setting !imported to see if this changes anything (try not to use this option as the solution)

```
.bntBgB {
 background-color: #122d98 !important;
}
```

If this option works it is a '[specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)' problem. If this style is added inline then you will have to use JavaScript to remove these styles or you can use the important option as shown above. If it is added via another style sheet either internal or external your in luck! and the mission my friend is to beat the '[specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)'.

> '[Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)' is a simple concept. Each css style selector combination, is given
>   marks as to how important they are. The higher the mark you get for
>   your selector combination the more likely it will supersede other competing styles. Follow the MDN
>   article for specificity that I have tagged for a more indepth view.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change css dynamically you can use jquery. please refer the code below to add css particularly or add class

To add class name dynamically.

```
$( "bntBgB" ).removeClass( "myClass noClass" ).addClass( "yourClass" );
```

To add css dynamically.

```
$("bntBgB").css("background-color");
```